# C++ “was not declared in this scope” compile error and modification tips

Tags: c++, accelerometer, arduino, atmega

I'm trying to modify this code in an attempt to make it work on an Arduino Mega. I'm pretty much new to C so, I may have made some major mistakes. By the way, this is for a self balancing skateboard. :P

This code is taken from an ATmega32 (from : [url=http://sites.google.com/site/onewheeledselfbalancing/Home/twin-wheel-self-balancing-skateboard-lightweight-version/code4]http://sites.google.com/site/onewheeledsel...t-version/code4[/url]  and I'm trying to make it work on a Arduino Mega.

This code was writen for an ATmega32  developpement board
http://www.active-robots.com/products/controllr/m32db.shtml

Thank you!

Here is the first error I encounter :

> In function 'void timer_init()':
>   error: 'TCCR0' was not declared in
>   this scope In function 'int main()':

Could someone explain me what is wrong?
I'm pretty much a beginner in programming but I've read a lot of books/website and I'm learning fast too! ^^
and here is the complete code (its pretty long):

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <math.h>
```

> ## define CLOCK_SPEED  16000000
>
> ## define OCR1_MAX   1023
>
> typedef unsigned char u8; void
>   set_motor_idle(void); void
>   InitPorts(void); float level=0; float
>   Throttle_pedal; float aa; float
>   accelraw; float x_acc; float accsum;
>   float x_accdeg;
>
> float gyrosum;
>
> float gangleratedeg; float
>   gangleraterads; float ti = 2.2;
>
> float overallgain; float gaincontrol;
>   float batteryvolts = 24; float
>   gyroangledt; float angle; float
>   anglerads; float balance_torque; float
>   softstart;
>
> float cur_speed; float cycle_time =
>   0.0064; float Balance_point; float a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5,
>   a6;//Savitzky-Golay variables for
>   accelerometer
>
> int i; int j; int tipstart; void
>   InitPorts(void) { PORTC=0x00;  //Port
>   C pullups set to low (no output
>   voltage) to begin with DDRC=0xFF;
>   //Port C pins all set as output via
>   the port C direction register //PORTC
>   |= (1<
>
> DDRA=0x00; //all port A pins set as
>   input PORTA=0x00; //Port A input
>   pullups set to low pullups
>
> DDRD=0xFF; //Configure all port D pins
>   as output as prerequisite for OCR1A
>   (PinD5) and OCR1B (Pin D4) working
>   properly
>
> PORTB=0x00;  //Port B pullups set to
>   low (no output voltage) to begin with
>   DDRB=0xFF; //All port B pins set to
>   output
>
> } /*   IO:   I am using ATMega32 16MHz
>   with external crystal clock. New
>   planned pin arrangement to OSMC motor
>   controller  PC4       Onboard LED     PD5/OC1A
>   ALI -> OSMC pin 6     PD4/OC1B   BLI ->
>   OSMC pin 8    PC1     Disable -> OSMC pin 4
>     PC2     BHI -> OSMC pin 7   PC3     AHI ->
>   OSMC pin 5    PA6/ADC6   Vbatt/10 ->
>   OSMC pin 3    PA1/ADC1   pitch rate gyro
>     PA0/ADC0   accelerometer  */   void
>   adc_init(void) {   /* turn off
>   analogue comparator as we don't use it
>   */   ACSR = (1 << ACD);
>       /* select PA0 */   ADMUX = 0;   ADMUX |=(1< Set ADC
>   prescaler to 128, enable ADC, and
>   start conversion */   ADCSRA = 0 |
>   (1<
>   /* wait until bogus first conversion
>   finished */   while (ADCSRA & (1 <<
>   ADSC)) {   } }*
>
> uint16_t adc_read(uint8_t channel) {
>   /* select channel */   ADMUX =
>   channel;   ADMUX |=(1< start conversion */
>
>   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);   /* wait until
>   conversion finished */   while (ADCSRA
>   & (1 << ADSC)) {   }   /* return the
>   result */   return ADCW; }*
>
> /* 156 cycles per sec, 6.4ms per cycle
>   MEASURED ON OSCILLOSCOPE*/ /* read all
>   the ADC inputs and do some conversion
>   */ void sample_inputs(void) {
>
> ```
> uint16_t adc0, adc1, adc2, adc3, adc4, adc5;
>  gyrosum=0;   adc0 = adc_read(0); /* accelerometer pin PA0 */   accelraw
> ```
>
> = (float) adc0;
>       for (j=0; j<7; j++) {
>         adc1 = adc_read(1);   //gyro pin PA1            gyrosum = (float) gyrosum +
>   adc1; //using a mean of 7 samples per
>   loop for the gyro so it gets a
>   complete update with each loop of the
>   program
>                           }
>
> ```
> adc2 = adc_read(2); /* grey wire overallgain (via cutout switch)
> ```
>
> position PA2*/   adc3 = adc_read(3);
>   /* Position lever pulled back position
>   PA3*/   adc4 = adc_read(4); /*
>   Throttle_pedal position PA4*/   adc5 =
>   adc_read(5); /* Position lever pushed
>   forwards position PA5*/   //adc6 =
>   adc_read(6); /* Vbatt input from OSMC
>   (not used at present) position PA6*/
>          //Sav Golay filter for accel only   a0 = a1;   a1 = a2;   a2 = a3; 
>   a3 = a4;   a4 = a5;   a5 = a6;   a6 =
>   (float) accelraw;   accsum = (float)
>   ((-2*a0) + (3*a1) + (6*a2) + (7*a3) +
>   (6*a4) + (3*a5) + (-2*a6))/21;  //Sav
>   Golay calculation
>
> ```
>     gaincontrol = (float) gaincontrol*0.9 + 0.1*adc2/341;
> ```
>
> //smooths any voltage spikes and gives
>   range 0-3
>           Throttle_pedal=(float) Throttle_pedal*0.9 + 0.1*adc4/341;
>   //smooths any voltage spikes and gives
>   range 0-3
>
> //Cuts the motor if the dead mans
>   button is let go  //(gaincontrol
>   variable also wired in through this
>   button to adc2   if (adc2<100) {
>         Throttle_pedal=0.001;
>         gaincontrol=0.001;
>           }
>        overallgain = gaincontrol*softstart;
>       //what to do if lever pulled back or pushed forwards or not doing
>   anything:    Balance_point = 514;
>          if (adc3>100) Balance_point=534;
>
> if (adc5>100) Balance_point=494;
>
> ```
>  PORTB |= (1<<PB2);//Port B2 turned on/off once per loop so I can
> ```
>
> measure loop time with an oscilloscope
>
> /*ACCELEROMETER signal processing*/
>       /*Subtract offsets*/
>       x_acc=(float) accsum - Balance_point; //accsum is SG value
>   for accelerometer, not a true "sum" so
>   no need to divide by 7
>        if (x_acc<-250) x_acc=-250; //cap accel values to a range of -250 to
>   +250 (80 degree tilt each way)   if (x_acc>250) x_acc=250;
>       /* Accelerometer angle change is about 3.45 units per degree tilt in
>   range 0-30 degrees(sin theta)     Convert
>   tilt to degrees of tilt from
>   accelerometer sensor. Sin angle
>   roughly = angle for small angles so
>     no need to do trigonometry. x_acc
>   below is now in DEGREES*/
>
> x_accdeg= (float) x_acc/-3.45;
>   //The minus sign corrects for a back
>   to front accelerometer mounting!
>
> ```
>   /*GYRO signal processing*/
>  /*Subtract offsets: Sensor reading is 0-1024 so "balance point"
> ```
>
> i.e. my required zero point will be
>   that reading minus 512*/
>
> /*Gyro angle change of 20mV per deg
>   per sec from datasheet gives change of
>   4.096 units (on the scale of 0 - 1023) per degree per sec angle change    This
>   limits the rate of change of gyro
>   angle to just less than the maximum
>   rate it is actually capable of
>   measuring (100deg/sec). Note all these
>   fractions are rounded up to an integer
>   later just before it is sent to the
>   PWM generator which in turn is
>   connected to the motor controller*/
>       gangleratedeg=(float)((gyrosum/7) - 508)/4.096; //gyrosum is a sum of a group of 7 samples so divide by 7 for
>   gyro value if (gangleratedeg < -92)
>   gangleratedeg=-92; if (gangleratedeg
>
> > 92) gangleratedeg=92   /*I turn port B2 on and off once per main program
> >     cycle so I can attach an oscilloscope
> >     to it and work out the program cycle
> >     time  I use the cycle time to work out
> >     gyro angle change per cycle where you
> >     have to know the length of this time
> >     interval*/    PORTB &= (0<
>
> /*ti represents scaling for the "i"
>   or integral factor (currently 2.2
>   here)     gyroangledt is anglechange
>   since last CYCLE in degrees from gyro
>   sensor, where ti is scaling factor
>   (should in theory be about 1 but 2.2
>   makes board feel tighter)
>
>     ganglerate is now in units of degrees
>   per second    aa varies the time
>   constant, i.e smaller aa value makes
>   accelerometer time constant longer as
>   it slowly corrects for the gyro
>   drift*/
>
> aa=0.005;
>         gyroangledt = (float)ti*cycle_time*gangleratedeg;
>   gangleraterads=(float)gangleratedeg*0.017453;
>
> /*new angle in DEGREES is old angle
>   plus change in angle from gyro since
>   last cycle with little bit of new
>   accel reading factored in*/    angle =
>   (float)((1-aa) * (angle+gyroangledt))
>   + (aa * x_accdeg); //the main angle calculating function*/   //Convert
>   angle from degrees to radians
>
> ```
>  anglerads=(float)angle*0.017453;
>       balance_torque=(float)(4.5*anglerads)
> ```
>
> + (0.5*gangleraterads);
>
> cur_speed = (float)(cur_speed +
>   (Throttle_pedal * balance_torque *
>   cycle_time)) * 0.999;
>
> /*The level value is from -1 to +1 and
>   represents the duty cycle to be sent
>   to the motor. Converting to radians
>   helps us stay within these limits
>       level = (balance_torque + cur_speed) * overallgain;
>
> }
>
> void timer_init() {   TCCR0 = 0 |
>     (1<
>
> // PWM mode is "PWM, Phase Correct,
>   10-bit"   TCCR1A = 0 |    (1<
>
> (1<
>
> void set_motor()
>
> /* The leveli terms is the level term
>   rescaled from -1023 to +1023 as an
>   integer ready to send to the PWM motor
>   control ports that are in turn
>   connected to the OSMC*/ {
>
> //if (level<-0.9) level=
>   -0.9;//checks we are within sensible limits   //if (level>0.9) level=0.9;
>
> int16_t leveli =
>   (int16_t)(level*1023); //NOTE here we
>   take the floating point value we have
>   ended up with for "level", we multiply
>   it by 1023 and then make it into an
>   integer before feeding the value into
>   the PWM generator as "leveli"
>
> if (leveli<-1020)
>   leveli=-1020;//double-checks we are
>   within sensible PWM limits as do not
>   want to suddenly be thrown off the
>   board   if (leveli>1020) leveli=1020;
>
> /Set up LED or buzzer on Port B1 to
>   warn me to slow down if torque to be
>   delivered is more than 50% of max
>   possible   The reason for this is that
>   you always need some reserve motor
>   power in case you start tipping
>   forward at speed   If motor already
>   running flat-out you would be about to
>   fall over at high speed!   Some use an
>   auto-tip back routine to automatically
>   limit top speed. For now I will do it
>   this way as easier/
>
> if (level<-0.7 || level>0.7) {
>   PORTB |= (1<
>   PORTB &= (0<
>
> softstart = (float) softstart+0.001;
>   if (softstart>1.0) softstart=1.0;
>
> ```
> //PORTC |= (0<<PC1);   // AHI=1  PinC3, BHI=1 PinC2 set both to ON for
> ```
>
> OSMC to work and both to OFF to shut
>   motor down /*NOTE: Not sure why but to
>   stop motor cutting out on direction
>   changes I had in the end to hard wire
>   AHI and BHI to +12V / / Un-disabled
>   OSMC by setting PinC1 output to zero,
>   a 1 would disable the OSMC*/   PORTC
>   |= 0x0c; //make C1 pulled down so
>   un-disables the OSMC i.e. enables it. 
>   PORTC &= ~0x02; //disable is off   if
>   (leveli<0) {
>         OCR1A = -leveli;   // ALI is PWM   going backwards as leveli variable is
>   a negative signed value, keep the
>   minus sign in here!   OCR1B = 0;     //
>   BLI = 0   }   else {  OCR1A = 0;     //
>   ALI = 0   going forwards as leveli
>   variable is a positive signed value
>     OCR1B = leveli; // BLI is PWM   }   }
>
> int main(void) {
>         InitPorts();
>
> adc_init();
>
> timer_init();
>
> /*  Initial tilt-start code  Turn on
>   micro while board tipped to one side, 
>   rider about to step onto it, if tilt
>   angle crosses zero (mid) point balance
>   algorithm   becomes operational
>   otherwise locked in this loop forever
>   until it is tipped to level position
>   as rider   gets onto board*/
>     tipstart=0;  accelraw = 0;
>
> while (tipstart<1){
>
> // you need this to allow the SG
>   filter to wind up to the proper stable
>   value when you first turn machine on,
>   before looking at the value of accsum
>   (below).
>
> for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
>   sample_inputs();
>                   }
>
> if (accsum<504 || accsum>524) {  //
>   if (x_accdeg>0) {         tipstart=0;      }
>     else {      tipstart=1;
>   softstart=0.4;     }  }
>
> angle=0;    cur_speed=0; /* end of tilt
>   start code. If go beyond this point
>   then machine has become level and is
>   active*/
>
> sei();
>
> while (1) {    sample_inputs();
>
> set_motor();
>
> } }

Comment: That's far too much code to wade through. Please post a minimal test case, which is just enough code to illustrate the problem while being complete (i.e. compilable).

Comment: By trying to reduce this code to the minimal subset that generates the error you will probably find the error.

Comment: This question needs a lot of cleanup work... at the least, format the code correctly in the body of the question so it can be read easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely have the wrong MCU specified for your build.  While DDRA exists on the ATmega1280 on an Arduino Mega, DDRA does not exist on the ATmega328 of a regular Arduino.

If you're using the Arduino UI, go to Tools | Board and choose Arduino Mega.

If you're using your own build system, you'll need to update the value that you specify for -mmcu= on the gcc command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, once I change the Board to an Arduino Mega, this error is no more. I have :



 In function 'void sample_inputs()':
error: '92' cannot be used as a function In function 'void timer_init()':
 In function 'int main()':

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have left off a closing comment here:

```
/*The level value is from -1 to +1 and represents the duty cycle to be sent to the motor. Converting to radians helps us stay within these limits >>>*/<<<
```

Comment: Good eye, but I don't think he got that far in his compilation. +1 Anyway, as there is no way this code could compile without this fix.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler tells you that something "was not declared in this scope," as yourself this question:

**What scope *was* is declared in?**

If you can't answer that question, then you've discovered the problem. After all, if *you* don't know what that name refers to, how can you expect the compiler to? Remember that *you* are the expert on any code *you* write.

If you *can* determine what scope the thing is declared in, then the next task is to determine how that scope relates to the scope you're trying to use it in. Typical problems include (but are not limited to) the following:

- It was declared in some other namespace. Use the `::` scope-resolution operator to give a fully qualified name.
- It was declared as a member of a class and you're trying to use it in a standalone function. Either find a instance of the class and access the variable or function through that object, or change the class to have your new function as one of its members.

If you *can't* find what scope it was declared in, then there are a few things that might be wrong:

- You've spelled it wrong. Check the spelling in the documentation and fix your code.
- It's declared in some header that you've forgotten to include. Figure out where it's declared and add the appropriate `#include` directive. **This is probably the problem in your case.**
- It's not declared anywhere. Figure out where it *should* be declared and declare it there yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to reasonably straightforward Arduino code for control of a DIY Segway.

This would be a better starting point for your skateboard I think.

http://diysegway.blogspot.com/

Best wishes

John